# Is it possible to bookmark an alternate URL

Tags: iphone, html, meta-tags, bookmarks

When a user tries to bookmark one of my pages, I really want it to bookmark a different URL (in my case a tel:// URL -- on the iPhone).  Is there a meta tag or something I can use to specify that the browser bookmark an alternate URL?

Comment: That's a little evil don't you think?

Comment: I think it might be if misused.  However, the web app I made (http://www.cliqcliq.com/speed-dial/www/), asks a user to do this sort of thing.  So I think it would be a very appropriate use.  I don't like evil either :)

Comment: Now with IDP, it should not be considered evil. Usually the protected site redirects to IDP. If the user bookmarks the IDP address, it won't work well next time. Looking for options... :(

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can, here is how you can do it:

For exemple:

```
Click <a href="javascript:window.external.AddFavorite(' tel://URL', 'name of the site')">here</a> to add my site to your bookmark.
```

Does this help you ?

Comment: I believe that's IE only.  I'm working strictly with Mobile Safari in this case.  However, a generally cross-browser solution would be interesting.